# Output layer in image classification

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am building a simple multi-layer perceptron that takes an image as an input and gives as an output the classification of the image. My image dataset is composed by grayscale images with size (n x m). I choose as input layer nm input neurons (in reality I am reducing dimensions with PCA, but let's keep it simple). Then I choose intermediate hidden layers. Now what should I choose as my output layer? How many neurons and why? My classification uses, say, L different classes (i.e., L different types of images). Should I use a single output neuron?

Comment: The output layer should contain `L` neurons, each neuron representing each of the image classes. Finally the neuron with the largest value would correspond to the class of the input image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have L different classes you should have L output neurons, in keras it would be :

```py
...
previous_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4096)(...)
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.nb_class)(previous_layer)
```

If you were in a binary classification you would need a sigmoid activation

```py
output = tf.keras.layers.Activation('sigmoid')(output)
```

If L > 2 then you would go for softmax activation.

```py
output = tf.keras.layers.Activation('softmax')(output)
```

Last thing, you should try some Convolutions layers before going for Dense layers. Look at VGG16 architecture.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work with just a single model (ML-NN),

if L = 2,

The number of neurons in the last layer can be just one with `sigmoid` activation (the most common approach).

You can also avoid sigmoid, and simply use a threshold to do the binary classification.

If L > 2,

The number of neurons should be L with softmax activation.

A special-case is a multi-label classification, in which you want to know if for a sample, there can be multiple classes or not.

Then, use L neurons with sigmoid activation.